# IBasicAudioEffect implementation in C++

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

I would like to implement a UWP AudioGraph custom effect.

I implemented it in C# successfully. I followed [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-audio-effects).
But this C# implementation is very difficult to optimize.

I would like to implement the effect in C++ instead of C#.
But I can't find a good tutorial. I added to my solution a C++ Windows Runtime Component project. And I added a class which implements IBasicAudioEffect.

Here is my ProcessFrame method implementation :

```
void PanningCustomEffect::ProcessFrame(ProcessAudioFrameContext^ context)
{
    if (_frame == nullptr)
    {
        if (context == nullptr)
        {
            throw ref new InvalidArgumentException("context");
        }
        _frame = context->InputFrame;
    }

    AudioBuffer^ inputBuffer = _frame->LockBuffer(AudioBufferAccessMode::ReadWrite);
    IMemoryBufferReference^ inputReference = inputBuffer->CreateReference();

    // TODO: here
}
```

I have 3 questions :

- How can I get a reference to IMemoryBufferByteAccess ?
- Then how can I access to the float values of the samples ?
- How to properly cleanup memory / destroy objects at the end of my method so that there is no memory leak ?

Comment: Not related to your question, but why use such API for audio effects?

Comment: Use [save_cast<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/casting-c-cx).  The automatic reference counting should take care of cleanup.

Comment: I was not able to use safe_cast. I used reinterpret_cast and QueryInterface() instead. Should I use Release() ?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I'm developping an audio creation application in C# on the UWP platform. It makes a heavy use of the AudioGraph API. I'm trying to rewrite some performance critical components in C++...

Comment: @Nicolas Séveno, Currently, there is no audio effect c++ code sample, and I have report this to the related team, Please pay attention to the following update. And you could also post your request in the windows universal code sample github [host](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples).

Comment: Thanks @NicoZhu-MSFT ! I spent few hours trying to implement the ProcessFrame method. See the answer below. It works, and it's more efficient than the C# implementation. But I will look at the official sample when it will be published.

Comment: I posted this request in the windows universal github : https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/1094

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this implementation of the ProcessFrame method :

```
AudioBuffer^ buffer = _frame->LockBuffer(AudioBufferAccessMode::ReadWrite);
IMemoryBufferReference^ bufferReference = buffer->CreateReference();

ComPtr<IMemoryBufferByteAccess> memoryBufferByteAccess;
if (reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(bufferReference)->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&memoryBufferByteAccess)) != S_OK)
{
    throw ref new Platform::InvalidCastException("Unable to get the IMemoryBufferByteAccess interface.");
}

BYTE* data;
UINT32 capacity;
memoryBufferByteAccess->GetBuffer(&data, &capacity);

float* floatData = (float*)data;
const int floatCapacity = capacity / sizeof(float);
for (int i = 0; i < floatCapacity; i++)
{
    float sample = floatData[i];

    // ...

    floatData[i] = sample;
}

delete bufferReference;
delete buffer;
```